# Find all permutations of length x that sum to s

Tags: java, permutation

I am trying to find the number of permutations of length n that sum to a value s. This is what I have so far:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<x+1; i++) {
        for(int j=s+1; j>0; j--) {
            sb.append(i);
            //sb.append(j);
            //sb.append(shares-i-j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Obviously, this doesn't work correctly. How do I change the code to return a string of all combinations of length x that sum to n? So eventually, I will need a string that reads something like this for (3,3): 003 030 300 102 120 111 etc. I have listed all possible values like so:

```
003
012
021
030
102
111
121
201
210
300
```

The order doesn't matter. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If the length is `x` then your first loop should be `for(int i=0; i<x; i++)` hope that helps. And as a generality, try to avoid using the same value (3) for both of your arguments in an example.

Comment: To check if the sum is x, wouldn't a int array be more appropriate?

Comment: @Gumbo *yes* in addition to the string. However the sum is `s` and the string is used to build the output.

Comment: I have added an edit to hopefully provide some clarification. Please see above. i<x does not work because we will have x+1 options where the first digit is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical case for recursion.

For f(0,0) -- empty strings that sum up to 0 -- there is one solution. For f(0, N) where N != 0, there are no solutions. This is the base case.

For a 3 digit string summing up to 3 as in your example, we have:

- All strings starting with 0, followed by two digit strings summing up to 3
- All strings starting with 1, followed by two digit strings summing up to 2
- etc

Or more generally, f(N, X) is the set of strings starting with a digit 0 <= D <= 9, followed by F(N-1, X-D).

Here's a simple, unoptimized, non-modular implementation of the above:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f("", 3, 3);
    }
    static void f(String prefix, int length, int sum) {
        if (length == 0) {
            if(sum == 0) {
                System.out.println(prefix);
            }
        } else {
            for(int i=0; i<=sum && i<10; i++) {
                f(prefix + i, length-1, sum-i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in an incorrect answer. `000000
00001
00100
0011
0110
012
10000
1001
1100
111
210
22`

Comment: For me this solution gives the correct result.

Comment: I don't know what happened. It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I like your question :-)

Here is my solution

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int n = 3; //Number of cifers
        int m = 3; //The sum

        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for(int j = 0; j < (int) Math.pow(10,n)-1; j++){

            arr[0]++;

            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                if(arr[i] > 9){     
                    arr[i] = 0; 
                    arr[i+1]++;
                }
            }

        if(sum(arr) == m ) print(arr);

        }
    }

    public static int sum(int[] arr){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void print(int[] arr){
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```